# Micronaut property injection does not work with Gradle multi-project build

Tags: java, gradle, micronaut

I am trying to setup Micronaut (`1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`) project with a shared package using Gradle multi-project build so I can put the common logic in one place.

I encountered the problem during the creation of the property file for the library. I put some library specific properties in `application.yml` but looks like they are not pushed forward to the application layer:

**lib/src/main/java/lib/CommonSingeton.java**

```
@Singleton
public class CommonSingleton {

  public CommonSingleton(
    @Value("${lib.testProperty}") String value
  ) {
    System.out.println(value);
  }
}
```

**lib/src/main/resources/application.yml**

```
lib:
  testProperty: test
```

**app/src/main/java/app/AppController.java**

```
@Controller("/app")
public class AppController {

  @Inject
  private CommonSingleton commonSingleton;

  @Get(produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String index() {
    return "Hello World";
  }
}
```

**The error is:**

```
Unexpected error occurred: Failed to inject value for parameter [value] of class: lib.CommonSingleton

Message: Error resolving property value [${lib.testProperty}]. Property doesn't exist
Path Taken: AppController.commonSingleton --> new CommonSingleton([String value])
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [value] of class: lib.CommonSingleton
```

The complete example is available [on Github](https://github.com/SirWojtek/micronaut-library-properties).

Comment: I think you will see the same thing if you copy your `lib.testProperty` definition to `app/src/main/resources/application.yml`.  Is that correct?

Comment: FYI... The question doesn't mention this but the linked project currently uses `1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`.  See https://github.com/SirWojtek/micronaut-library-properties/blob/f6b5191d7b58f49c613b777c0183be49829250f2/app/build.gradle#L23 and https://github.com/SirWojtek/micronaut-library-properties/blob/f6b5191d7b58f49c613b777c0183be49829250f2/lib/build.gradle#L16.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I've added the version to the post.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown No, after I move the property to the application layer it is injected to the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is designed to just read a single `application.yml`. If you were to remove the file from `app`, it would be read from `lib`. You can file an issue to make us aware this is something you want. https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I've created the issue as you said: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1357